# Find minimum and maximum values input by the user without using an array

Tags: c++

I know in theory that I would, for the maximum, replace the current value with the new integer that the user inputs if it is higher than the latter, and vice versa for the minimum, but I can't how to make this happen with my code. Essentially I am asking if there is a way for me to compare two integers without storing their data.

This is a bit of the code that I have thus far. I have found the average, the amount, and the sum of the integers entered as well as the amount of even and odd integers. I now just need to show the minimum and maximum integer values.

```
int main()
{
    int intVal;
    int sum = 0;
    int maxValue = -1;
    int minValue = -1;
    double average = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int evenCount = 0;
    int oddCount = 0;

    cout << endl << "Enter an integer (negative value to Quit):  ";
    cin  >> intVal;
    cout << endl;


    while(intVal >= 0)
    {
        count ++;
        sum += intVal;
    
        if(intVal > 0)
            average = sum / count;
    
        if(intVal % 2 == 0)
            evenCount ++;
        else
            oddCount ++;
       
        cout << "Enter an integer (negative value to Quit):  ";
        cin  >> intVal;
        cout << endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: "if there is a way for me to compare two integers without storing their data" I don't think there is such way. The integers to compare should be stored somewhere (memory or registers).

Comment: `if (intVal > maxValue) { maxValue = intVal; }`, etc. You will want to change what you initialize min with, right now the value you used will be smaller than anything entered.

Comment: Initializing `int maxValue = -1;` and `int minValue = -1;` will miss finding values. E.g.. What will `minValue` be if all entered values are positive? What will `maxValue` be if all values entered are negative? Use [std::numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to set proper initial values. (see `min()` and `max()` member functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare and update if it should be updated:

```
if (maxValue < 0 || intVal > maxValue) maxValue = intVal;
if (minValue < 0 || intVal < minValue) minValue = intVal;
```

detail:

```
if (                 // if
  maxValue < 0       // there are no value yet (this is the first value)
  ||                 // or
  intVal > maxValue) // new value is larger than current maximum,
  maxValue = intVal; // update the maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that might help you wrap your head around it

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getmin(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < b)
  {
    return a;
  }
  else
  {
    return b;
  }
}

int getmax(int a, int b)
{
  if (a > b)
  {
    return a;
  }
  else
  {
    return b;
  }
}

int prompt()
{
  int val;
  cout << "Enter an integer (negative to quit): ";
  cin >> val;
  return val;
}

int status(int current, int evens, int odds, int minimum, int maximum, int sum)
{
  cout << "=== Stats (last: " << current << ") ==="
    << "Odds: " << odds << endl
    << "Evens: " << evens << endl
    << "Min: " << minimum << endl
    << "Max: " << maximum << endl
    << "Sum: " << sum << endl
    << "Avg: " << sum * 1.0 / (evens + odds) << endl
    << "Total: " << odds + evens << endl
    << "======" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int current = 0;
  int evens = 0;
  int odds = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  int minimum = INT32_MAX;
  int maximum = INT32_MIN;

  while (true)
  {
    current = prompt();
    minimum = getmin(minimum, current);
    maximum = getmax(maximum, current);

    if (current < 0)
    {
      break;
    }

    sum += current;

    if (current % 2 == 0)
    {
      evens += 1;
    }
    else
    {
      odds += 1;
    }

    status(current, evens, odds, minimum, maximum, sum);
  }

  cout << "Exiting" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that `getmin` and `getmax` can be swapped out for the C++ algorithm implementations

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you find the minimum and maximum, it is important to always initialize the values to the highest and lowest values that the type can hold, respectively. Otherwise, depending on the range of values entered, your max and min can fail to capture the maximum or minimum values.

Now by choosing to only allow positive numbers and zero, you mitigate against that possibility somewhat, but take your `minValue = -1;` for example. If you only accept positive numbers as you do, your `minValue` will never change because the user cannot enter anything less than `0` according to your code.

To initialize the variables to capture the maximum and minimum values, C++ provides [std::numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) and in particular the [std::numeric_limits::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) and [std::numeric_limits::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) member functions.

To initialize variables to capture the maximum and minimum integer values, you would initialize as follows, e.g.:

```
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
        max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

With `min` set to the **maximum** possible values and `max` set to the **minimum** possible value. So no matter what value is entered, there is no possibility of the entered value falling outside of your initialization.

As for looping and finding `max` and `min` without storing in an array, etc..., you can do that with a simple *ternary* as a shorthand `if ... else ...`, or it is perfectly fine to use a full `if ... else ...` for each `min` and `max`. Using a ternary, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {
    
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
        max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        n;
    
    while (std::cin >> n && n >= 0) {
        max = n > max ? n : max;
        min = n < min ? n : min;
    }
    
    std::cout << "\nmin: " << min << "\nmax: " << max << '\n';
}
```

(the code above will break the read-loop upon entry of any value less-than zero)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/minmaxlimits
1
9
7
13
2
449
8
-1

min: 1
max: 449
```

The key here being, don't adjust your `max` and `min` initialization values just because you are limiting input to positive values. If you always initialize using the `max()` and `min()` numeric limits, you will never go wrong.